# Android Glide not showing png images

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using `Glide` in my project for loading images. I have custom gallery activity in which I am showing all images from the device. The problem is Glide is not showing any png image present in the phone. In place of that it is showing error image which I had set as fallback. I am unable to figure out what went wrong:

This is my code to query:

```
Cursor imagecursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);

        if (imagecursor != null && imagecursor.getCount() > 0) {

            while (imagecursor.moveToNext()) {
                CustomGalleryModel item = new CustomGalleryModel();
                int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                item.sdcardPath = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
                galleryList.add(item);
            }
        }
```

And in my adapter:

```
File f = new File(data.get(position).sdcardPath);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    Glide.with(context).load(uri).placeholder(R.drawable.no_media)
            .error(R.drawable.car_bg).into(holder.imgQueue);
```

The path of PNG image is as follows:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_20160622-160641.png
```

**Update**

Problem in if an image is in Screenshots folder then Glide is showing error image. If I copy the same image inside sd card at some other place, then it displays properly.

Comment: Have you tried using just the media store Uri directly, rather than the file path? Can you attach a link to an image that fails? Can you attach a stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make change like this following in Glide statement:

```
.load(new File(pictureUri.getPath())) // Uri of the picture
```

Comment: I am already creating file from sd card path and then loading the uri. Again  getting path back would not make any sense. I tried by all available options in Glide. The actual problem in if an image is in Screenshots folder then Glide is showing error image. If copy the same image inside sd card at some other place. Then it displayes properly. Not getting idea why its happening

Comment: omg, it's mysterious. I think this may caused by your phone. Sometimes my phone still get into this situation, I take screenshot or even a photo from camera but it didn't show in gallery immediately until several hours or even a day long.

Comment: @Nitish did you figured out the problem back then? I guess the issue is  with png images rather than particular folder.